# Convert API Request Response to List python

Tags: python, json, api

I wrote a python API request call, the script looks like this:

```
import requests  
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1  
import json  

def PULL():  
    url = "someURL"   
    ConsumerKey = "someKey"  
    ConsumerSecret = "someSecret"  
    Token = "someToken"  
    TokenSecret = "someToken"  

    auth = OAuth1(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, Token, TokenSecret)
    r = requests.request("GET", url, auth=auth)  
    data = r.json()  
    print data  

PULL()
```

Then I used Terminal on my Macbook Pro and I got the following response:

```
{u'watermarked': 0, u'orientation': u'landscape', u'datePublished': u'2016-05-25T13:49:30Z', u'extension': [u'jpeg']}
```

How do I turn it into a list so the data looks like this?

```
watermarked: 0  
orientation: landscape  
datePublished: 2016-05-25T13:49:30Z   
extension: jpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are after not having the curly braces and the `u'...'`unicode string literals on output, than simply do not `print data` but instead:

```
for key, value in data:
    print '%s: %s' % (key, value)
```

That should give:

```
watermarked: 0
orientation: landscape
datePublished: 2016-05-25T13:49:30Z
extension: jpeg
```

on output (the order taken for granted and determined by the "dict loading process").

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know how I can remove the curly braces and the "u" from my response?

Comment: Your response is something stored in a python dict (thus the curly braces) and as this is Python v2, the string literals here are capable to hold Unicode characters (thus `u'...'` as compared to `'...'`). whilst the usual str type holds bytes. When using Python v3, the "strings" have been unified and more separated from plain bytes (without associated "meaning" i.e. "encoding"). tl;dr: "Removing these things" is not "undecorating" them, but unpacking the content of the used container, leaving the "meaning" of the content intact and serializing/encoding them into a different shape/format.

Comment: In short: I understand from the question, that some practicing of Python basic types and especially python unicode howto reading would be a great series of next steps.